# MonoTouch on iPad: How to make text search faster?

Tags: c#, algorithm, search, optimization, xamarin.ios

I need to do text search based on user input in a relative large list (about 37K lines with 50 to 100 chars each line). The search is done after entering each character and the result is shown in a `UITableView`. This is my current code:

```
if (input.Any(x => Char.IsUpper(x)))
    return _list.Where(x => x.Desc.Contains(input));
else
    return _list.Where(x => x.Desc.ToLower().Contains(input));
```

It performs okay on a MacBook running simulator, but too slow on iPad.

On interesting thing I observed is that it takes longer and longer as input grows. For example, say "examin" as input. It takes about 1 second after entering e, 2 seconds after x, 5 seconds after a, but 28 seconds after m and so on. Why that?

I hope there is a simple way to improve it.

Answer (score 5):

Always take care to **avoid** memory allocations in time sensitive code.

For example we often produce code often allocates `string` without realizing it, e.g.

```
x => x.Desc.ToLower().Contains(input)
```

That will allocate a string to return from `ToLower`. From your description this will occurs **many** time. You can easily avoid this by using:

```
x = x.Desc.IndexOf ("s", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1
```

note: just select the `StringComparison.*IgnoreCase` that match your need.

Also LINQ is nice but it hides allocations in many cases - maybe not in your case but *measuring* is key to get things faster. In that case using another algorithm (like suggested in another answer) could give you much better results (but keep in mind the allocations ;-)

**UPDATE:**

Mono's `Contains(string)` will call, after a few checks, the following:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf (this, value, 0, length, CompareOptions.Ordinal);
```

which, with your `ToLower` requirement that using `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` is the *perfect* (i.e. identical) match for your existing code (it did not do any culture specific comparison).

Comment: I just tried it using IndexOf with StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase and the same thing is done in half time (e.g. enter m took 12 sec vs 28 sec. I never understood the difference between OrdinalIgnoreCase and CurrentCultureIgnoreCase, but to my surprise, using CurrentCultureIgnoreCase is much slower: for the same scenario "exam", x took 12 sec, a took 27 sec, and enter m my iPad crashed after waiting for 2 minutes and 20 sec. Can anybody explain why is it so different?

Comment: Simply put it can't be simpler than `Ordinal` - that's a byte[] comparison. Ignoring case does not add much processing. However culture-aware comparison rules are **much more** involved, e.g. "æ" and "ae" would be identical (for some cultures) but would fail on ordinal.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation of `Ordinal`. I'm confused by your UPDATE: Are you saying there should be no difference between using `ToLower().Contains` and `IndexOf` with `OrdinalIgnoreCase`? How come I observed big performance improvement of the latter?

Comment: You'll get the same **result** between the two. However they are different code paths, the one with `ToLower` will **allocate** memory while the one with `IndexOf` won't - that's what makes my suggestion perform better than the original code.

Answer (score 1):

Generally I've found that contains operations are not preferable for search, so I'd recommend you take a look at the [Mastering Core Data Session](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=118) (login required ) video on the WWDC 2010 page (around the 10 min mark). Apple knows that 'contains' is terrible w/ SQLite on mobile devices, you can essentially do what Apple does to sort of "hack" FTS on the version of SQLite they ship.

Essentially they do prefix matching by creating a table like:

```
[[ pk_id || input || normalized_input ]]
```

Where input and normalized_input are *both indexed* explicitly. Then they prefix match against the normalized value. So for instance if a user is searching for 'snuggles' and so far they've typed in 'snu' the prefix matching query would look like:

```
normalized_input >= 'snu' and normalized_input < 'snt'
```

Not sure if this translates given your use case, but I thought it was worth mentioning. Hope it's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a trie. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie